# Closing bootstrap alert with jQuery not working with this code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this div:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="login-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" id="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    Incorrect username or password.
</div>
```

which is hidden on page load with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login-error').hide();
});
```

I want to hide it when the user clicks the close button contained within the alert (it's shown when incorrect login details are supplied using .show();).

To do that I have this code from another Stackoverflow post:

```
$('.alert .close').on('click', function(e) {
$(this).parent().hide();
});
```

However, clicking the close button does not hide it and I have no idea why. If anyone could explain to me why it doesn't work so I can fix it that would be great :) Thanks.

Comment: i don't see any problem http://jsfiddle.net/n8x48/ ?

Comment: Weird. http://defensedpt.com/personnel/PTS/login.php

Put anything into the username/password and click login, then try and close the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this case, the answer is simple.  You don't have jQuery loaded.

Check out the errors in the console:

[image]

Also, once you load jQuery before your bootstrap.js file as required, you don't need to write your own script to handle closing the alert.  Instead, you can just include the data-dismiss markup as described in the doc **[here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)**:

> Just add data-dismiss="alert" to your close button to automatically
>   give an alert close functionality.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
$('#close').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#login-error').hide();
});
```

or

```
$("#close").click(function() {
    $('#login-error').hide();
});
```